# Recover data from unreadable SD card

Tags: android, sd-card

It's an 8GB micro SD card.
It was on my Sony Xperia android smartphone, I almost never removed it from the phone.
Suddenly about a month ago, the phone displayed a message saying that the card is not formatted, so I removed it from the phone and formatted it using my PC.
It was working normally until yesterday when the phone displayed a message saying that the card was removed, but it was obviously still inside the phone.
The phone is working normally with any other micro SD card.

I've tried inserting the card directly in the PC card reader but it won't detect anything. When I try using a USB card adapter, it shows partially as removable disk E:,but if I try to open I get a "Please insert disk into removable disk E:" and chkdsk is reporting "Cannot open volume for direct access".

I used the card mostly for music, but there is a couple of photos I'd like to have back. Is there anything I can do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1.Plug in **SD card**.

2.Check for the drive letter under **my computer**.  Look at the SD that was inserts **Example** Drive H:sdcard.

3.Open up the Cmd.exe (**Hold Windows Key and R**) type in **cmd** hit **Run**.

4.Type in "**chkdsk**" then your card's **drive letter,** followed by a colon and **/f**.

Example

```
chkdsk h: /f
```

Ending result your **uncurrupted** SD card.

Pop it back in your phone and you are good to go.

Used this several times for clients and friends.

Comment: I tried hat, but  "Cannot open volume for direct access" again.

Comment: Most of the time you can't access the volume. Did it at least show a drive letter?

Comment: Yes. But only when I insert the SD card using a USB card reader.